# How to do a sub-select per result entry in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.3

Assume I have a table with only two columns: `id`, `maturity`. `maturity` is some date in the future and is representative of until when a specific entry will be available. Thus it's different for different entries but is not necessarily unique. And with time number of entries which have not reached this `maturity` date changes.

I need to count a number of entries from such a table that were available on a specific date (thus entries that have not reached their maturity). So I basically need to join this two queries:

```
SELECT generate_series as date FROM generate_series('2015-10-01'::date, now()::date, '1 day'); 
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable WHERE mytable.maturity > now()::date;
```

where instead of `now()::date` I need to put entry from the generated series. I'm sure this has to be simple enough, but I can't quite get around it. I need the resulting solution to remain a query, thus it seems that I can't use for loops.

***Sample table entries:***

```
id | maturity
---+-------------------
 1 | 2015-10-03
 2 | 2015-10-05
 3 | 2015-10-11
 4 | 2015-10-11
```

***Expected output:***

```
    date    | count 
------------+-------------------
 2015-10-01 |                 4 
 2015-10-02 |                 4
 2015-10-03 |                 3 
 2015-10-04 |                 3 
 2015-10-05 |                 2
 2015-10-06 |                 2
```

**NOTE:** This count doesn't constantly decrease, since new entries are added and this count increases.

Comment: And the output is based on which input?

Comment: I've provided a more exhaustive sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use fields of outer query in `WHERE` clause of a sub-query. This can be done if the subquery is in the `SELECT` clause of the outer query:

```
SELECT generate_series,
  (SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM mytable
  WHERE mytable.maturity > generate_series)
FROM generate_series('2015-10-01'::date, now()::date, '1 day');
```

More info: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group your data by the maturity Date.

Check this:

```
select maturity,count(*) as count 
from your_table group by maturity;
```